# Simple twitter module recommendation

Tags: 7, social-network

Can anyone recommend me a simple twitter module which will enable me to include twitter feeds on my site? I am using a corporate clean theme and would like to display it in the middle column of the footer section.

Comment: Twitter provides several widgets that are not Drupal-specific but will work on any website and can easily be cut and pasted into a block: https://twitter.com/settings/widgets

Answer (score 6):

You should use the [Twitter](http://drupal.org/project/twitter) module.

> This module provides API integration with the Twitter microblogging service. Out of the box, it allows users to:
>
> - Associate one or more Twitter accounts with their Drupal user account
> - List tweets in different ways thanks to Views
> - Post to their own Twitter account or a site-wide Twitter account whenever they create new content or based on Drupal Actions or Rules
> - Log in to your Drupal site via Twitter
> - Format twitter @usernames and #hashtags as links to Twitter.com

Answer (score 2):

If your needs are simple I would choose a [Twitter widget](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines). If you need more advanced integration then I would suggest the [Twitter module](http://drupal.org/project/twitter), perhaps along with [Twitter Pull](http://drupal.org/project/twitter_pull) (7.x-2.x-dev), as that is basically the only option with OAuth authentication which will be required when Twitter shuts down API v.1, if they haven't already done so. Most other Twitter modules will no longer work when that happens, and right now the Twitter module is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

The [Twitter Block](http://drupal.org/project/twitter_block) module provides configurable blocks for a Twitter feed.

Other Tweet modules which might be useful are:

- [Tweet button](http://drupal.org/project/tweetbutton) adds the Twitter buttons to your nodes.
- [Twitter](http://drupal.org/project/twitter) provides API integration with the Twitter microblogging service. Out of the box, it allows users to:

  - Associate one or more Twitter accounts with their Drupal user
    account
  - List tweets in different ways thanks to Views
  - Post to their own Twitter account or a site-wide Twitter account whenever they create new content or based on Drupal Actions or Rules
  - Log in to your Drupal site via Twitter
  - Format twitter @usernames and #hashtags as links to Twitter.com

Comment: Please stop deleting your answers: Deleting them can cause you to be answer banned. If that happens, you would not be anymore able to answer anymore to any question, until you don't get more reputation by asking questions. See [Should I delete my answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146403/should-i-delete-my-answers) Even in the case the answer is wrong, that would help the users who answer the question after you.

Comment: I didn't know that it's wrong. I won't do that any more unless I realy have to. Thank you for pointing that out, I appreciated it.

Answer (score 0):

The [Twitter](https://www.drupal.org/project/twitter) module is your best bet. I know it can be intimidating at first but just follow the directions and you should be fine. Here's a step by step.

1. download and install the module.
2. go to https://apps.twitter.com/app/new and register your application
3. then go to admin/config/services/twitter/settings and enter your OAuth Consumer key and OAuth Consumer secret and save
4. Then go to admin/config/services/twitter and add an authenticated account. You can also add other users accounts.

Once you've done all that, you can use views to pull in tweets and display them in pages and blocks.

Hope this helps you out.